# typedef struct used for definition

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Why does using Node(..Node{..), as below, while defining a struct type gives a compile time error.

```
typedef struct node Node;

Node{
  int data;
  Node *next;
};
```

There is a very basic concept that is confusing me, please advise or refer me to a relevant link.

Comment: could you please revise your first sentence in order to make clear what you expect it to do or to be?

Comment: It is not valid because it is not valid. A definition of struct type must begin with keyword `struct`. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

Typedef is used to provide an alias to some another type. It is not a macro, it is not substituted for something at the place of use.

The correct definition might be:

```
typedef struct node {
  int data;
  struct node* next;
} Node;
```

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, you need it to say

```
typedef struct node Node;

struct Node{
  int data;
  Node *next;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

However, you *can* do this:

```
typedef struct {
  int data;
  struct Node *next;
}Node;
```

Now you can easily create instances of the struct `Node` you have created by:

```
Node node, *pNode;
```

Where `node` is the name of a new variable of type `struct Node`.
and `*pNode` is a pointer to the same, initialized by:

```
  pNode = &node;
```